# Exporting webmap into PDF without layout using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf

I try to export a webmap in using arcpy into a pdf. This works fine, if there is a [Layout](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) available using:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ConvertWebMapToArcGISProject(webmap, None, None, notes_gdb)
aprx.importDocument("C:\\path\\to\\the\\layout.pagx")
layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
layout.exportToPDF("C:\\temp\\export.pdf")
```

Is there a posibility to export the webmap without layout?

There are resolution, scale and extent given in the webmap, so it should be possible. But I have nothing found to export a map directly like what is possible in [arcpy.mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm).

Comment: Have you tried just exporting a MapFrame rather than the Layout?  That has an exportToPDF method too.

Comment: How do I get the map frame without a layout?

Comment: I think you would add the MapFrame to a Layout, but then there is no need to export the Layout just the MapFrame.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I loaded a dummy layout with one map frame, choose the frame and called exportToPDF. The result was a crash of arcgis pro

Answer (score 1):

I got a hint from the default esri server printing tool box. This tool box has been in general a source of inspiration, how to handle printing issues.

```
result = arcpy.mp.ConvertWebMapToArcGISProject(webmap)
mapView = result.ArcGISProject.listMaps()[0].defaultView
dpi = int(result.DPI) #a workaround for now for a bug
mapView.exportToPDF("C:\\temp\\export.pdf", result.outputSizeWidth, result.outputSizeHeight, dpi)
```